# Basic information is nearly impossible to find on SE

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments

Key facts:

- What's "basic" for someone depends on the expertise the person has in a given topic
- What's "basic" also changes with time due to the development of mankind themselves
- If there is a big gap between a person reading or writing the question, the question will be perceived as either too complex or too basic (not useful) by the reader
- Both of which have the tendency to have the reader instantly press the downvote button
- The average level of expertise in each area (including in how to use SE in the first place) will rise due to the tendency that veterans stay on the site for years and years to come
- This means that the likelihood that a newcomer receives offensive feedback (this includes downvotes on a newcomer's first question) for a question they ask rises with the age of SE (I bet SE has data which shows a decline in adoption rate, a rise in complaints of newcomers about the offensiveness of the site and a rise in downvotes received on first questions submitted by newcomers)
- This means furthermore that basic questions a newcomer has are nearly impossible to easily find, because the search engine devalues questions by other newcomers asked before which got downvoted or negatively moderated

Actually the common opinion I read in Meta that newcomers more and more ask "stupid" or "spam" questions supports all of those claims.

**Solution**

Maybe the effect downvotes have on "basic" questions could be reduced.
For example, the search engine could ignore downvotes on newcomer questions if newcomers search for that particular question, or a similar one. But I feel like this is a very bad idea. Because how could the search engine possibly know if something is a "basic" question or not? This would reduce the perceived quality of answers found by newcomers which might be worse than some initial understanding issues.

Actually I think the root cause is how the voting functionality is used. The overlying intent (beneath some others) of the voting buttons is that the search engine can decide which question/answer is useful and which is not. This allows the search engine to provide the most relevant questions/answers to someone who is searching. So the community is encouraged to upvote useful questions/answers and downvote useless ones. But now my question becomes, how should someone know if a question/answer is useful? It *certainly* is for the person writing the text, otherwise they wouldn't have wasted their time.

Comment: Better solution: do a quick search to find your answer, get your answer and don't ask a question at all. The odds of a newbie question not already being in Stack Overflow, let alone the wider Internets, is pretty slim.

Answer (score 10):

> It certainly is for the Person writing the Text, otherwise he wouldn't have wasted his time.

That can be true, but especially for the problematic newbie questions it is not sufficient to only look at it from this perspective.

Zero efforts "here my homework now drop solution. Asap. Please" are a complete waste of time for readers. And the questioner actually didn't waste time because zero efforts spend!

One part of reality here is that there are plenty of users who don't care about quality or community. They want someone else to do their work. And when you informed them that this is not going to happen, they often get rude and disrespectful.

That is a real problem, and fast voting is the only answer we have to it.